# Passing a value by reference to List.Add()

Tags: c#, list, reference

How could I pass a value by reference to the `List`?

```
int x = 2;
List<int> newList = new List<int>();
newList.Add(x);

System.Console.WriteLine(x);
x = 7;
System.Console.WriteLine(newList[0]);
newList[0] = 10;
System.Console.WriteLine(x);
```

My objective is elements on the list to be related with the previous ones. In C++ I would use a list of pointers, however right now I feel hopeless.

Comment: You could make it a list of `object` and let them be boxed on their way in.. ?

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea anyway.

Comment: Classes are reference types.  Just declare a class with property of type *int*.  Easy peasy.

Comment: @Simon, beside being a bad solution, it wouldn't even work. How does he reassign new value of boxed int which is already in the collection?

Comment: @Simon, I don't think making the type a reference type means it will be passed by reference, if that's what you mean. Either that, or I'm helplessly confused :) And making the type parameter an object seems to defeat the purpose of generics.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I tried, and it's not possible with object.because boxing and unboxing performing automatically.Actual value never change

Comment: Good point. Didn't really read the whole question. Its too early for me :(

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it with value types.You need to use a reference type.

(change) You can't do it with object too, you need to define your custom class which has a int property. If you use object it will be automatically perform boxing and unboxing.And actual value never affected.

I mean something like this:

```
MyInteger x = new MyInteger(2);
List<MyInteger> newList = new List<MyInteger>();
newList.Add(x);

Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
x.Value = 7;
Console.WriteLine(newList[0].Value);
newList[0].Value = 10;
Console.WriteLine(x.Value);

class MyInteger
{
  public MyInteger(int value)
  {
        Value = value;
  }
  public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I wonder how you got that output, given that `List<object> newList = new List<int>()` does not even compile.

Answer (score 1):

ints are primitives, so you are not passing around a pointer,but the value it self.

Pointers are implicit in C#,so you can wrap ints in an object and pass that object around instead and you will be passing a pointer to the object.

Answer (score 1):

You can't store value types in a .NET generic collection and access them by reference. What you could do is what Simon Whitehead suggested.

I see few solutions of this problem:

1) Create a class which will hold the integer (and possibly other values you might need)

2) Write "unsafe" code. .NET allows usage of pointers if you enable this for your project. This might even require creating custom collection classes.

3) Restructure your algorithm to not require references. E.g. save indexes of values you wish to change.